# Multiple Bootstrap Modals one after another. Is it possible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am new to bootstrap. I have a situation where I have to Show a Bootstrap Modal, When I click any button on that Modal I'll have to show another modal below that 1st Modal (Not Stackable). If I close the 1st Modal 2nd Modal has to go up to replace the position.

Is it possible ?

I tried to Show a Bootstrap Modal, and when I click any button I am setting modal height to sit next to the 1st modal. But That uses constant height value. if I change browser/computer it causing me problems.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick.

[bootstrap-modal/](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/)

Comment: I think that is stackable. I need to show modals one after another

Comment: can't you just call the modal from the submit button on the prev <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" href="#2ndmodal">Send</button>

Comment: Yes I can, But How Can I place it in next to the 1st modal ? Not on the 1st Modal